# Avoiding pointers in this C++ linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, pointers

As I know it is not good idea to have so many pointers in c++ code.
But I have written this simple implementation of linked list in c++ and there are many pointers in it, how can I improve that?
Also as I tried I can not use functions in algorithm module on this linked list, how can I make this class compatible with those?

```
template <typename T>
class linkedlist {
private:
    struct node {
        node() : T() {
        }

        node(node * prev, node * next, const T & data) :
                prev(prev), next(next), data(data) {
        }

        node * next;
        node * prev;
        T data = T();
    };

    node first;
    node last;

public:
    linkedlist() :
            first(nullptr, &last, T()),
            last(&first, &last, T()) {
    }

    class iterator {
        friend class linkedlist;
    private:
        node * current_node;

    public:
        iterator(node * current_node) : current_node(current_node) {
        }

        T & operator*() {
            return current_node->data;
        }

        const T & operator*() const {
            return current_node->data;
        }

        iterator & operator++() {
            current_node = current_node->next;
            return *this;
        }

        bool operator!=(const iterator & other) {
            return current_node != other.current_node;
        }
    };

    void add(const T & data) {
        node * new_node = new node(last.prev, &last, data);
        new_node->prev->next = new_node;
        new_node->next->prev = new_node;
    }

    bool remove(iterator & iterator) {
        if (iterator.current_node == &first || iterator.current_node == &last)
            return false;
        node *to_remove = iterator.current_node;
        to_remove->prev->next = to_remove->next;
        to_remove->next->prev = to_remove->prev;
        delete to_remove;
        return true;
    }

    iterator begin() {
        return iterator(first.next);
    }

    iterator end() {
        return iterator(&last);
    }

    iterator find(const T & data) {
        for (iterator it = begin(); it != end(); ++it) {
            if (*it == data) {
                return it;
            }
        }
        return end();
    }
};
```

Comment: Who told you having many pointers in C++ is bad?

Comment: Which algorithms have you tried to use from `algorithm`? Certain algorithms require certain iterator traits (for example, `std::partition` requires a Bidirectional Iterator). In your case, you could only use algorithms that work with at most a ForwardIterator (as your iterator can only move forward). See this chart for more info: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/

Also, pointers by themselves are not bad; it's how you (ab)use them that's usually the problem.

Comment: There are two main places to have pointers in C++ (but not the only ones). Smart pointers contain pointers. Containers usually contain pointers. These are resource management constructs and implementing them efficiently requires pointers. Pointers themselves are not bad. The problem with pointers is establishing the ownership semantics of the pointer. If you contain and define the ownership of semantics of the pointer then there should be no problem. Just **DO NOT** leak pointers out of your object.

Comment: @Bizkit yes, I tried `find` and it didn't worked, thank you for the link :-)

Comment: @LokiAstari thank you for the helpful explanation. so when should I am supposed to use smart pointers?

Comment: If you are not building a "Smart Pointer" or a "Container" then you should probably not be using a pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see some things that may help you improve your code.

### Write member initializers in declaration order

One of the constructors for `node` looks like this:

```
node(node * prev, node * next, const T & data) :
        prev(prev), next(next), data(data) {
}
```

That looks fine, but in fact, `next` will be initialized *before* `prev` because members are always initialized in *declaration* order and `next` is declared before `prev` in this class. To avoid misleading another programmer, you should swap the order of those such that it says instead:

```
node(node * prev, node * next, const T & data) :
        next(next), prev(prev), data(data) {
}
```

This way the initialization actually proceeds from left to right as one might expect at first glance.

### Eliminate the default constructor

At the moment, one of the constructors for `node` is written like this:

```
node() : T() { }
```

However, this is not good at all since, if it were ever used, it would leave `next` and `prev` uninitialized.  Better would be to explicitly delete it like this:

```
node()  = delete;
```

### Add a destructor

Because you're allocating memory with `new` you must also deallocate it with `delete` or your program will leak memory.  Here's one way to write it:

```
virtual ~linkedlist() {
    for (auto it = begin(); it != end(); it = begin()) {
        remove(it);
    }
}
```

### Provide move semantics for iterators

Right now, it's not possible to do this:

```
linkedlist<std::complex<float>> ll;
ll.remove(ll.begin());
```

The reason is that `ll.begin()` is an ["rvalue"](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference) and so can't be passed as a reference.  To fix this, create a version of `remove` with move semantics:

```
bool remove(iterator &&iterator) {
    if (iterator.current_node == &first || iterator.current_node == &last)
        return false;
    node *to_remove = iterator.current_node;
    to_remove->prev->next = to_remove->next;
    to_remove->next->prev = to_remove->prev;
    delete to_remove;
    return true;
}
```

### Provide `const` versions of iterators

The `cbegin()` and `cend()` forms of the iterators are missing.  Here's a simple `cbegin()`:

```
iterator cbegin() const {
    return iterator(first.next);
}
```

### Provide an `initializer_list` constructor

At the moment, this form of the constructor doesn't work:

```
linkedlist<std::complex<float>> ll{{3,4}, {5,12}};
```

It's simple to add, however:

```
linkedlist(std::initializer_list<T> list) :
        first(nullptr, &last, T()),
        last(&first, &last, T()) 
{
    for (auto &item : list) {
        add(item);
    }
}
```

### Provide copy function or delete it

At the moment, a copy function is compiler generated but almost certainly not what you want because it will only copy pointers and not the underlying data.  Either delete the function explicitly or provide one.

### Provide member functions to suit the data structure

A linked list is not a very good data structure for many purposes, but one thing that is efficient is the ability to insert one linked list within another (a `splice`).  Unfortunately, this function is not provided, so any advantage is unrealized.

### Provide a full iterator implementation

In order to use the algorithms in `<algorithm>`, you will need first class iterators, but although somewhat useful, yours are missing a number of pieces.  See [this reference page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator) for details on what a real iterator provides.

Comment: Another question @Edward. How should I implement input iterator?